# How to use Microsoft SQL Server extended events to see the set options?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am using extended events to log the query plan. I would also like to see the set options. How can I do this using extended events? (I know the profile shows the set options, but can this also be done using extended events?)

**Background**

I have a .NET core application that uses Entity Framework Core.

1. I connect to one database using a context and execute a LINQ query
2. And then within the first context I use `SqlConnection` + `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader` to execute a query directly on a 2nd database. The `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader` is slow (compared to direct execution in SQL Server Management Studio) and I would like to know what SET options are enabled.

Here is the pseudo code

```
using (var context = new MyDBContext(options))
{
    var sensor = await context.Set<Sensor>()
                              .AsNoTracking()
                              .Where(s => s.Id == 4)
                              .SingleAsync(cancellationToken);

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString2))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            try
            {
                reader.Read();
                value = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CountColumn"]);
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    var newResult = new Result(sensor.Id, value);
    context.Set<Result>().Add(newResult);
    sensor.LatestResult = newResult;
    context.Set<Sensor>().Update(sensor);

    await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: Probably running the SQL Server Profiler would allow you to check what you are looking for. To start it open the SQL Server Management Studio and `Tools -> SQL Server Profiler`

Comment: Highly unlikely that the `SET` options themselves are causing the issue, it's generally a complete myth. It is really the fact that different `SET` options can cause a recompilation, which can be an issue with skewed data and parameter sniffing. You need to really look at your execution plans, not your `SET`. See also [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)